# type conversion VHDL

Tags: type-conversion, vhdl

I'm trying to write a driver for a MS5541C pressure/temperature sensor, but it doesn't seem like I'm able to.
The datasheet provided some calculations which, if I put them into excel seems to work pretty fine.
But when I try to write VHDL code for it and display it on a 7segment display it doesn't work.

The calculations provided are:

```
UT1 = 8 * C5 + 10000
```

where C5 is calibration data read from PROM

```
dT = D2 - UT1
```

Where D2 is the temperature read from the DAC

```
TEMP = 200 + dT*(C6+100)/2^11
```

Where temp would be the actual temperature in 0.1 Celsius and C6 is also a calibration temperature.

In my case C5 = 2223 (dec), D2 = 28144 (dec) and C6 = 53.
With these numbers I get a temperature of 22.7 degrees Celcius.

The code (MCVE) I use in VHDL is:

```
LIBRARY IEEE;
USE IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;

use ieee.numeric_std.all;

ENTITY MS5541C_CONVERTER IS

PORT(
        CLK     : IN STD_LOGIC;
    RST     : IN STD_LOGIC;

    T_OUT   : OUT STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(15 DOWNTO 0)
);
END ENTITY;

ARCHITECTURE MS5541C_CONVERTER OF MS5541C_CONVERTER IS

Constant C5     : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(11 DOWNTO 0) := "100010101111"; -- Reference temperature
Constant C6     : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR( 6 DOWNTO 0) := "0110101"; -- Temp coefficient of the temperature

Constant D2     : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(15 DOWNTO 0) := x"6df0"; -- temperature

BEGIN

PROCESS (CLK,RST) 
    VARIABLE UT1    : SIGNED(33 DOWNTO 0);
    VARIABLE dT     : SIGNED(33 DOWNTO 0);
    VARIABLE TEMPE  : SIGNED(33 DOWNTO 0);
    VARIABLE C5_s   : SIGNED(33 DOWNTO 0);
    VARIABLE C6_s   : SIGNED(33 DOWNTO 0);
BEGIN
    C5_s := RESIZE(signed(C5),33);
    C6_s := RESIZE(signed(C6),33);
    IF RST = '1' THEN

    ELSIF rising_edge(CLK) THEN
        UT1 := 8 * C5_s + 10000;
        dT  := RESIZE(signed(D2),33) - UT1;
        TEMPE := 200 + dT*(C6_s + 100)/ 2048;
        T_OUT <= STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(RESIZE(TEMPE,16));
    END If;
END PROCESS;
END ARCHITECTURE;
```

The result of this is 2674(dec) or a72(hex) (actual numbers may differ a little bit from the excel because these are two measurements, but this isn't even close)

I've reread the calculations a few times and even tried different approaches, but the results are never correct. I assume it has something to do with the conversions of the types, but I don't know what.

P.s.
for the person who wants to read the datasheet:

http://media.digikey.com/pdf/Data%20Sheets/Measurement%20Specialties%20PDFs/MS5541-CM.pdf

Comment: Turn these snippets into an MCVE. It's OK to use your example values as Constants, no need for ports, just an empty Entity and your declarations and a simple process in the architecture. What's an MCVE? http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @BrianDrummond Done

Comment: You have basic bound check failures in this code ... how did you simulate it? In which simulator? If in Xilinx ISIM, you need to turn runtime checking ON, they are off by default which is an insane choice in a simulator.

Comment: I see, I didn't simulate, I programmed it straight into the FPGA. ISE did give a warning, but I failed to check it. The fact that it needs 98 bits seems quite strange to me, since the datasheet says it only uses 64.

Comment: Well it doesn't need 98 bits,  the whole thing is a mess of inappropriate types and word lengths. Re-sizing to 33 bits and storing into a 34 bit vector doesn't help! Having got it working in a spreadsheet, examine what happens at the highest and lowest temperatures, and restrict ranges there. Then use the most appropriate types for each stage : UNsigned or Natural  for things that can (and should) never be -ve : that would catch the error QuantumRipple pointed out. I recommend ranged integers for most of it, only converting to low level types where you absolutely have to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At least one problem is that when you do the signed conversion for C5, you are left with -4984, not 2223. You then extend this negative number to 33 bits wide.

If that was the only problem, your final result would be something like 4534, so there is probably another problem, but neither of your other constants that you convert to signed has a leading `'1'`.

Are C5, C6, D2 actually signed numbers? are they actually 12/7/16 bits wide as read from the prom?

I hope your clock is very slow or this isn't for synthesis, although I suspect you intend to use this in a real system. This kind of math, using variables instead of signals, will have extremely long paths to do it all on one clock cycle. 33 bit operands (on the wide side) exacerbate this problem.

Speaking of operand length, your math will be more efficient if you figure out the maximum value each calculation and operand will hold and use appropriate lengths. The optimizer may fix some of this, but they aren't always perfect.

Comment: Thank you, it was indeed the signed part! now the result is 226!

I'm currently using a 50MHz clock. You suggest that I should use signals instead of variables?

I've casted the Cx types to 32 bits because I thought that would do the job and worry about the width later on when everything works.

Comment: So I guess that fixed it? It seems that your number returns in 10ths of a degree, so 226 (22.6) matches up pretty closely with your expected temperature of 22.7.

Also the temp calculation you listed (`TEMP = 200 + dT*(C6+100)2^11 + 1000`) doesn't match what you're doing in VHDL; I'm guessing the division slash is missing before the "2^11" but I don't know where the "+ 1000" was supposed to come in.

You might be okay at 50 MHz, but you should implement timing constraints, or at least make sure the tool's proposed fmax is above 50MHz (tools try to guess when you don't provide constraints).

Comment: I'd typically pipeline math like this to about 10 clock cycles using explicit DSPs, but I'd be able to run it at 500 MHz, which is why you might be okay not doing pipelining.

Comment: I've never heard about DSPs or pipelining, but I'd like to read up on that. My books don't cover it (Zwolinski & Pedroni), do you have any suggestions where I can learn more about it?

Comment: Folks at work have recommended "The Designer's Guide to VHDL", but honestly I never cracked a book for VHDL. I used online syntax references and learned techniques and style from more experienced coworkers.

I wrote a doc page on timing that mentions pipelining at the end (after explaining why you might need it), but it doesn't cover the nitty gritty of exactly what you need to do to implement pipelining. http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/vhdl/5936/static-timing-analysis-what-does-it-mean-when-a-design-fails-timing/20821/what-is-timing#t=201610251454138575029

Comment: DSP (Digital Signal Processor) blocks in FPGAs are just hardened blocks that do math more efficiently than the general purpose LUTs (Look-Up Tables) that are used to implement most of your logic. A hardened block just means that there is native silicon logic to do that function instead of it being an abstraction built up from LUTs+FFs. The LUTs/FFs are also hardened blocks, but not typically thought of that way as they are the basic fabric that the other hardened blocks augment. The other most common hardened block is the BRAM (Block RAM) that creates wide and deep memories more efficiently.

Comment: Thank you, I'm certainly going to read it! The block ram I'm familiar with! I'm using that in an other design. Do I also need to setup DSPs via the IP core generator or is there a different way to do it? (I'm writing this driver for a much larger project and I think it would be more convenient to just pass hdl files instead of the IP core files)

Comment: You don't need to use the IP core generator for any primitives, although you can. They can be directly instantiated as found in the Xilinx libraries guide for your product. Lots of folks use wrappers (that you write) around these primitives though, so it is easier to migrate to new versions with later parts and to leave off some of the MANY generics/ports that you might not have a use for. BRAMs and DSPs can also be inferred if your coding style matches what the compiler expects.